# NoSuchMethodError and Dependency pom order

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jetty, cxf

I'm facing a strange situation.

In a very messy project (typical bad practice scenario at all), which obviously I can't modify very much, I'm working to my child module project (not entirely made and programmed by me at the moment, just assigned some coding task to do in it), which has a ton of parent dependencies.

Since I'm in need of a Jetty Server (Jetty 8), I've added it to my pom, plus the cxf-bundle which seemed to be needed.

The project works fine If I put:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0.v20160908</version> 
        </dependency>
        <!-- --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.8</version> 
     <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    ...
```

Please notice I've chosen that Jetty since should be the latest Jetty 8 dependency on Central (Why jetty 8? I'm working with JDK 1.7...), and the cxf bundle is taken a bit randomly: I've tried to choose a cxf version which would be temporal-near to Jetty.

The cxf-bundle exclusions are there since without them, it won't compile anymore.

This way, jetty wakes up, I'm able to do an:

> Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:1243/test", new
>   MyWsTestClassImpl());

...and everything works.

But, if I put those dependencies just before the enclosing `</dependencies>` tag I got:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.setupMessage(Lorg/apache/cxf/message/Message;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.serviceRequest(JettyHTTPDestination.java:338) ~[cxf-bundle-2.6.8.jar:2.6.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:312) ~[cxf-bundle-2.6.8.jar:2.6.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:72) ~[cxf-bundle-2.6.8.jar:2.6.8]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1088) ~[jetty-server-8.2.0.v20160908.jar:8.2.0.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1024) ~[jetty-server-8.2.0.v20160908.jar:8.2.0.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) ~[jetty-server-8.2.0.v20160908.jar:8.2.0.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255) ~[jetty-server-8.2.0.v20160908.jar:8.2.0.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) ~[jetty-server-8.2.0.v20160908.jar:8.2.0.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:366) ~[jetty-server-8.2.0.v20160908.jar:8.2.0.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494) [jetty-server-8.2.0.v20160908.jar:8.2.0.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:973) [jetty-server-8.2.0.v20160908.jar:8.2.0.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1035) [jetty-server-8.2.0.v20160908.jar:8.2.0.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:641) [jetty-http-8.2.0.v20160908.jar:8.2.0.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:231) [jetty-http-8.2.0.v20160908.jar:8.2.0.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82) [jetty-server-8.2.0.v20160908.jar:8.2.0.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696) [jetty-io-8.2.0.v20160908.jar:8.2.0.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53) [jetty-io-8.2.0.v20160908.jar:8.2.0.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) [jetty-util-8.2.0.v20160908.jar:8.2.0.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) [jetty-util-8.2.0.v20160908.jar:8.2.0.v20160908]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
```

I've found that method would be in another cxf library which is:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.8</version> 
    </dependency>
```

But even if I add that, I got same old stack.
Since I'm a bit scared of this kind of monster projects, and I'm firmly convinced that a programmer has to know what's happening, I've decided to dig with you this problem, since I didn't got the solution so far.

Comment: [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), consider upgrading.  even to Jetty 9.2.x (which is still at Java 7)

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Starting/Jetty_Version_Comparison_Table
Here tells 1.8 for Jetty 9

Comment: Follow the link in the big red warning at the top that tells you wiki.eclipse.org is out of date.  https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html

Comment: Oh my God, you're right. I thought it would be useless since the jdk advertisement of that page wouldn't be different...!! I'll try new jetty and report...